# What the 'serializer for text/html; charset=UTF-8; doesn't exist' error means?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubectl

Today I tried to see the PODs from a Kubernetes namespace and this error started to happen:

```
serializer for text/html; charset=UTF-8; doesn't exist
```

When I execute the follow command:

```
 .\kubectl.exe -n hml get pod
```

What is the cause for this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to connect to the **Azure VPN** to access the kubernetes environment. I just needed to do this.

After connect to the VPN, the error was gone. Sadly the error does not describe very well the cause.

As I was behind a company proxy, I think without the VPN the proxy itself changed the `Content-Type` request header to `text/html` on the connection, making the Kubernetes show this error because it was expecting another `Content-Type`.

Comment: why wiykd you need to do that?

Comment: @4c74356b41 the infrastructure guys of the company control the access to this environment and the only possible way to connect is using this VPN (that uses the `SSTP` protocol and a certificate).

Comment: I don't think this should be the accepted answer as it does not provide a solution to the problem described above.

Comment: @PrasadK, I added some details about the possible cause. Maybe this makes the answer more clear and can help other people with similar issue. Thanks for the feedback. It's not the best answer, but this worked for me.